# Numerically solving advection equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the advection equation:

$$Ut + aUx = 0, U(x, 0) = f(x)$$

on the interval $A=[-1 \space \space \space 1]$

The exact solution is a periodic version of U(x, t) = f(x − at). Take A =
a = 1.
Compute the numerical solution with N points at $t = T$. Note
that you need to solve the ODEs for the Fourier coefficients exactly to avoid
errors from the time-stepping

My question:
I don't understand what the initial condition is since it just says $U(x, 0) = f(x)$. What is $f(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

This is your initial condition. It tells you that for $t=0$ your distribution of $U(x,t=0)=f(x)$. Imagine $U$ would be the temperature, then $U(x,t=0)=f(x)$ means that you have the Temperature $f(x)$ at position $x$. An $f(x)$ is just an arbitrary function.